# Appending to buildcommands in premake

Tags: premake

I'm using a premake makefile project with the configurations: `{"VulkanDebug", "VulkanRelease", "OpenGLDebug", "OpenGLRelease"}` and want to pass `DEBUG / RELEASE` and `VULKAN / OPENGL` tokens to the script in `buildCommands`.

For example, when the configuration is `VulkanRelease`, the buildcommand is `script.bat VULKAN RELEASE` and the script is responsible for deciding what to do with those tokens.

My ideal solution is (using invalid logic):

```
    buildcommands { "script.bat" }

    filter "configurations:*Vulkan*"
        buildcommands.append(" VULKAN")
        rebuildcommands.append(" VULKAN")

    filter "configurations:*OpenGL*"
        buildcommands.append(" OPENGL")
        rebuildcommands.append(" OPENGL")

    filter "configurations:*Debug*"
        buildcommands.append(" DEBUG")
        rebuildcommands.append(" DEBUG")

    filter "configurations:*Release*"
        buildcommands.append(" RELEASE")
        rebuildcommands.append(" RELEASE")
```

If I use `buildcommands` the normal way, visual studio will consider it as three separate commands to execute: `script.bat`, `VULKAN`, and `RELEASE`.

I have a few workarounds but they all feel ugly to me. First is to pass the entire configuration name as an argument to the script and parse it there. Not really a fan of clumping arguments together like that. The second is to create command line arguments to the premake script for `VULKAN` or `OPENGL` and only have `DEBUG` and `RELEASE` as the configurations. As far as I know this will generate separate project files for Vulkan and OpenGL, which seems like overkill. Finally, I could supply the full build command for each configuration. This third option seems the best but it will make the script longer once I add more configurations (and all possible permutations).

So if premake has append support and I don't know about it, then non-issue! Otherwise there might be a cleaner way of doing this that I don't know about. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the cleanest approach that you can use right now today is to provide a helper function in your project script, which you then call from an inline token. Maybe something like:

```
-- Helper function to assemble the arguments
function buildArguments(cfg)
    local args = {}

    if cfg.name:find("VULKAN") then
        table.insert(args, "VULKAN")
    end

    if cfg.name:find("OpenGL") then
        table.insert(args, "OPENGL")
    end

    if cfg.name:find("Debug") then
        table.insert(args, "DEBUG")
    end

    if cfg.name:find("Release") then
        table.insert(args, "RELEASE")
    end

    return table.concat(args, " ")
end

-- Use it like this
buildcommands "SomeCmd.exe %{buildArguments(cfg)}"
```